# Design an algorithm, find the most frequently used word in a book

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, hash

An interview question:

Find the most frequently used word in a book.

My idea:

Use a hash table, traverse and mark the hash table.

If the book's size is known, if  any word is found to be used > 50%, then skip any new words in the following traversal and only count old words.  What if the book size is unknown?

It is O(n) and O(n) time and space.

Any better ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Changed the tags, let me know if not appropriate.  Doesn't seem a language-specific question.

Comment: Hashing is good heuristic, but it doesn't get exact answer (in fact two string may be hash to same int) Also, if you want to find most frequency word, I think you should skip words like `the, then,...` because they will be most frequency with high probability, but this isn't good news for everyone to know this book have `the` as most frequency word.

Comment: user1002288, you are getting a lot of bad advice on this thread. Almost all answers are coming from a practical/implementation perspective which probably isn't what the interviewer is looking for. You probably want to look at this from a theoretical perspective. If you ask this question on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ you'll probably get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Usually [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is the data-structure which suits well when we have to determine something like most/least used.

Even [Python;s Counter.nlargest](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is used for these purposes is implemented through the Heap Data-structure.

A Binary Heap Data-structure has the following Complexity

```
CreateHeap - O(1)
FindMin - O(1)
deleteMin - O(logn)
Insert - O(logn)
```

I ran a comparition on Hash (using default dictionary in Python) and Heap (using Collections.Counter.nlargest in python) and the Hash is fairing slightly better than Heap.

```
>>> stmt1="""
import collections, random
somedata=[random.randint(1,1000) for i in xrange(1,10000)]
somehash=collections.defaultdict(int)
for d in somedata:
    somehash[d]+=1
maxkey=0
for k,v in somehash.items():
    if somehash[maxkey] > v:
        maxkey=k
"""
>>> stmt2="""
import collections,random
somedata=[random.randint(1,1000) for i in xrange(1,10000)]
collections.Counter(somedata).most_common(1)
"""
>>> t1=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt1)
>>> t2=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt2)
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=10)/10)
38168.96 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=10)/10)
33600.80 usec/pass
```

Comment: To make the answer more complete, would you mind spelling out the time and space complexity of a heap-based solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Aix, actually the wiki link had the information. Any way I will add it here which will make more sense

Comment: `stmt1` can be optimized: `max(((v, k) for k,v in somehash.iteritems()))`

Comment: @reclosedev, I just ran over this optimized stmt, yet the difference is negligible

Comment: @Abhijit, `Counter` is not based on `Heap` [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f0666e56a552/Lib/collections.py#l356), it only uses [heapq.nlargest](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f0666e56a552/Lib/collections.py#l426) function to find most common elements. And about time comparison, all times are close enough. I'm getting `dd: 22686.73; cnt: 22744.79; ddopt: 20243.07`

Comment: It appears your arguing that Counter would be the fastest solution, and then you post a benchmark showing Hash (default python dict) as the fastest solution?  Aren't you defeating your own argument?

Answer (score 2):

To determine complexity I think you need to consider two variables, n = total number of words, m = number of unique words.  I imagine the best case complexity will come out close to O(n log(m)) for speed, and O(m) for storage, assuming each time you iterate over each of n words, and build and search based on a hash table or other such structure which eventually contains m elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a classic example of [map reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

The example in the wikipedia page will give you the word count of each unique word, but you can easily add a step in the reduce step that keeps track of the current most common word(with some kind of mutex to deal with concurrency issues).

If you have a distributed cluster of machines or a highly parallelized computer this will run much faster than using the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generalization of your optimization- if the book size is known and any word you have seen has a count > the remaining number of words + the next-highest count, your current highest-counted word is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, fast, and probably the best/easiest from a practical standpoint.

The other poster's solutions have worse time complexities than your solution. For a hash, as you are using, the time complexity is indeed O(n). Each insertion is O(1) and there are n words, so the insertion phase costs O(n). Iterating through and finding the max is then O(n). The space is also O(n) as you mentioned.

Note that you will not be able to terminate your algorithm early using Chris's solution because searching your hash table is costly and there is no way for you to perform this in O(1) time after each insertion.

A heap will cost more in time because you need to maintain the heap during each insertion. A heap insertion is O(log(n)) and thus the total cost for insertion will be O(nlog(n)).

Comment: One think you probably have ignored. The complexity in generating a hash key.

Comment: Are you saying generating a hash key takes more than O(n) time? Please explain. Applying the hash key for each insertion takes O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a book, then you know the vocabulary and the approximate word frequencies. Even if you are not given this information up front, you can get a good estimate by scanning a random sample.

For the exact answer, I would use a perfect hash function of the k most common words. A perfect hash function requires O(k) memory and guarantees fast worst-case O(1) lookup.

For the uncommon words, I would use a priority queue implemented as a heap or a self-balancing tree. A regular hash table might also be a good choice.